# Are hamlc files still necessary in haml 4x+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, hamlc

Our app was previously using haml 3.1.x and haml-coffee, and have now upgraded to 4.0.x. We have hamlc templates, and we were using haml-coffee-assets gem.

Do we still need hamlc files, and will they still transpile properly, or do I need to get rid of the hamlc files now?

Comment: HAML user of 6+ years here and I've never had a hamlc file. I do use a few coffeescript blocks in my haml files and rails takes care of the all just like it would do with javascript blocks.

Answer (score 0):

`hamlc` files are frontend javascript templates, they are not related to and not handled by the `haml` gem itself, they only share syntax, so you still need them and `haml-coffee-assets`